# Dynamic dropdown/select values and Validation issues

Tags: solspace-freeform

I am using the Freeform 4.0.12 along with ExpressionEngine v2.6.1 for forms in one of my projects and I have a situation where I need to display drop down values dynamically - based on what value was chosen in the previous dropdown.

Similar to a country/province dropdown - Eg. If I choose USA - then my province dropdown is filled with places from the USA, but if I choose India, then the provice dropdwon is filled with places in India.

Any idea how I can incorporate something like this?

Also, i am having an issue with the validation of the select fields. I am supposed to make them required. I tried using the inline errors and making the fields required. for example {freeform:field:country} - when I put this in, if I don't choose any option, by default the first value is chosen, if I manually enter all the values, then the validation works in the sense that the form is not submitted, but it doesnt display the field required error.

I could really use some help in there areas.

Comment: Hey Sucharitha - first, please make each question a single question, as people may have an answer to one and not the other in this case. What have you tried re: inline validation in Freeform? Please post your code.

Comment: Ooo! I am so sorry, will remember to post separately from next time. I managed to solve both the issues this morning - the validation problem was that I forgot to add the           {if freeform:error:my_field}          <span class="error">         {freeform:error:my_field}           </span>{/if}
 block for my select boxes and the other issue was solved using php/jquery and ajax as I posted below. Thanks so much :D

Answer (score 1):

Ok I managed to solve the dynamic dropdown values using some php/jquery and ajax, but I still have issues with the validation of the dropdown values. Can someone help me on that one?

Answer (score 1):

I think, you are using "FreeForm Pro" and having "Select" field type for the country. And you are listing the countries within "Field Options" of field settings.

You should select "Value/Label List" from "List type" and for the first option put label like "-- Select Country --" with empty value. Now your country validation would work fine as the first/default country option will be submitted empty.

Share your further findings.